# Why TypeScript assumes { ...Omit<Type, Missing>, ...Pick<Type, Add> } to be Omit<Type, Missing> & Pick<Type, Add>?

Tags: typescript

I am working on a generic function to add fields one-by-one to partial objects of an unknown type in a type safe and strongly typed manner. The function would replicate this concrete behaviour:

```
type Test = { a: string, b: number, c: boolean } // The type of the object to construct

type Missing = 'a' | 'b' // The fields missing from the partially complete object
type Add = 'b' // The field to add to the partially complete object

const partial: Omit<Test, Missing> = { c: true } // Current object
const toAdd: Pick<Test, Add> = { b: 2 } // Extend with...
const result: Omit<Test, Exclude<Missing, Add>> = { ...partial, ...toAdd } // Result
```

The above example has no typing issues. The function signature would look like this:

```
function add<
    Type extends object,
    Add extends Missing,
    Missing extends keyof Type = keyof Type> (
        partial: Omit<Type, Missing>,
        field: Add,
        value: Type[Add]
    ): Omit<Type, Exclude<Missing, Add>> {
  // code comes here
}

const added: Pick<Test, 'b' | 'c'> = add(partial, 'b', 2)
```

Again, other than the missing implementation, this has no typing issues. The obvious implementation would be simple:

```
return { ...partial, [field]: value }
```

, however this fails because:

```
const toAdd: Pick<Type, Add> = { [field]: value } // Type '{ [x: string]: Type[Add]; }' is not assignable to type 'Pick<Type, Add>'.(2322)
```

Ok, this is a known problem of narrowing (https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13948) - so I need to cast and should work... nope:

```
const toAdd = { [field]: value } as Pick<Type, Add>
const result: Omit<Type, Exclude<Missing, Add>> = { ...partial, ...toAdd }
// Type 'Omit<Type, Missing> & Pick<Type, Add>' is not assignable to type 'Omit<Type, Exclude<Missing, Add>>'.(2322)
```

This is apparently caused by TypeScript (wrongly) associating the type `Omit<Type, Missing> & Pick<Type, Add>` to the right hand side of the assignment, that is - again - not narrow enough. The mistake is likely when `Missing` and `Add` are not disjunct, something like `{ ...{ a: string }, ...{ a: number } }` is becoming `{ a: number }`, not `{ a: string & number }`, which is `{ a: never }` as implied by TypeScript.

As I am trying to avoid casts, and was already forced to have one due to the known issue above, looks like another one is required, but it gets worse...

```
const result = { ...partial, ...toAdd } as Omit<Type, Exclude<Missing, Add>>
// Conversion of type 'Omit<Type, Missing> & Pick<Type, Add>' to type 'Omit<Type, Exclude<Missing, Add>>' may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other. If this was intentional, convert the expression to 'unknown' first.(2352)
```

My question would be if my assessment is incorrect above and I am mistaken expecting that `{ ...Omit<Type, Missing>, ...Pick<Type, Add> }` should always yield `Omit<Type, Exclude<Missing, Add>>` given that `Type` is constrained to be an `object`?

---

TL;DR

In my actual use-case, the function is a bit more complicated, the partial object is not only missing the fields, it can also have them in the wrong way, so the concrete example would be:

```
type Test = { a: string, b: number, c: boolean }

type Missing = 'a' | 'b'
type Add = 'b'

const partial: Omit<Test, Missing> & OptionalRecord<Missing, unknown> = { b: null, c: true }
const toAdd: Pick<Test, Add> = { b: 2 }
const result: Omit<Test, Exclude<Missing, Add>> & OptionalRecord<Exclude<Missing, Add>, unknown> = { ...partial, ...toAdd }
```

, where

```
type OptionalRecord<K extends string | number | symbol, V> = { [key in K]+?: V } // a variant of Record<K, V> where the fields are optional
```

In this - extended - version, the function signature looks like this:

```
function add<
    Type extends object,
    Add extends Missing,
    Missing extends keyof Type = keyof Type>(
        partial: Omit<Type, Missing> & OptionalRecord<Missing, unknown>,
        field: Add,
        value: Type[Add]
    ): Omit<Type, Exclude<Missing, Add>> & OptionalRecord<Exclude<Missing, Add>, unknown> {
  // code comes here
}
```

, and though I ran into the same problem, this implementation worked without `as unknown as whatever`:

```
const toAdd = { [field]: value } as Pick<Type, Add>
const result = { ...partial, ...toAdd }
  as { [key in keyof Type]: key extends Missing ? key extends Add ? Type[key] : never : Type[key] }
  as Omit<Type, Exclude<Missing, Add>> & OptionalRecord<Exclude<Missing, Add>, unknown>
```

, with no complaint about type incompatibility.

Comment: ① Your TL;DR is approximately as long as the thing it summarizes. ② It's a limitation of TS that generic conditional types are mostly too much for the type checker to analyze; see [this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/54508#issuecomment-1575140739) which links to relevant GitHub issues. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz Thank you for you rply, yes, unfortunately the links in the comment pretty much explain what's going on :/ please them as an answer and I'll accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately the TypeScript type checker is unable to perform much analysis of types that depend on [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameters like `Type`, `Missing`, and `Add`, especially when these types involve [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) like [`Exclude`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#excludeuniontype-excludedmembers) and therefore like [`Omit`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#omittype-keys).  Such types are largely *opaque* to the type checker; they are like black boxes with a label on them, and the only way to be sure that two boxes are the same is if they have identical labels.  Since the label "`Omit<Type, Missing> & Pick<Type, Add>`" is not *identical* to "`Omit<Type, Exclude<Missing, Add>>`", we can't expect them to be seen as compatible.

The way that a human being sees them as the same is that we can try to *abstract* what `Omit`, `Pick`, and `Exclude` do for arbitrary inputs, and use higher order reasoning about invariants that persist.  The idea that, for example, `Omit<T, K> & Pick<T, K>` should, in some sense, be equivalent to `T`, is a product of such reasoning.  The type checker can verify this equivalence for *specific* instances of `T` and `K`, but it has no ability to abstract over arbitrary/generic types to see the equivalence.  See [microsoft/TypeScript#28884](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/28884) for a relevant feature request and discussion.

When such issues are raised, the TypeScript maintainers tend to treat them as design limitations, as in [microsoft/TypeScript#43846](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/43846), or sometimes bugs, as in [microsoft/TypeScript#37768](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/37768).  Maybe in the future some of these will be addressed, but they will likely be tailored to specific cases. The general situation will probably persist forever.  TypeScript is not intended to be a [proof checker/assistant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_assistant) where you can convince it of novel abstract relationships between types; if it's not already hardcoded in, the compiler will never see it.

So, if you want code like yours to compile without error, you will almost certainly need to keep using [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) (you're calling that a "cast" but that term is best avoided since it seems to mislead people into thinking there is a runtime effect; use "type assertion" instead). Which means you need to carefully check that your analysis is correct or good enough for your purposes (e.g., there are cases where `Omit<T, M> & Pick<T, A>` is not identical to `Omit<T, Exclude<M, A>>`, like when `M` is `string`; do you care? probably not).  The compiler can't verify correctness, so you have to take that responsibility on yourself.